# SVN commit via Jenkins authentication fail

Tags: svn, jenkins

After build I am trying to commit some file via command:

```
svn commit AndroidDev --force-log -F AndroidDev/BuildNumber.txt
```

On my PC it works just fine, but on Jenkins I get this error:

```
svn commit AndroidDev --force-log -F AndroidDev/BuildNumber.txt
svn: E215004: Authentication failed and interactive prompting is disabled; see the --force-interactive option
svn: E215004: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E215004: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'http://####'
svn: E215004: No more credentials or we tried too many times.
Authentication failed
```

Comment: By the way looking at the error, SVN does not receive any password, and obviously the interactive mode is disabled...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have much information to understand what's going on on your Jenkins server.

By the way with the last Jenkins update the SVN default authenticator was giving us a lot of trouble so we've installed the "Subversion Plugin"

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Subversion+Plugin

It is working very well, and the credential management is easier then before...

[image: Credential management]

Answer (score 1):

Faced this problem, and tried so many different alternatives including the subversion plugin but it didn't fit my use case. Finally, I found that this solved the problem.

```
sudo svn commit -m "Commit Msg" --username=uname --password=pwd <folder>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

After long time using svn without problems i unexpectedly got exactly the same error.

svn client on Mac, version 1.8.9

```
cd project_svn_root_directory
svn log -l 5
```

It will offer to enter credentials and store them.

This fixed E215004 error for me.